# What's the "Rails way" to route a "diff" between two instances of the same model?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes, ruby-on-rails-5, rails-routing

I'm building a ["Brand personality" tool](https://makelight.com/brand) that gives you a report based on the text you share on social media.

I have a model `PersonalityReport` and in routes I have `resources :personality_reports`.

A new feature is to offer a "diff" between two reports and I'm trying to work out the most "guessable" way to model this in routes.

Ideally I'd like `GET /personality_reports/:personality_report_id/diff/:id` or something along those lines, and while I could simply put that into routes as a GET route, is there a more Railsy way of specifying a route using the `resources` / `collections` style so that my `routes.rb` file is more easy to understand?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The 'neatest' way  can think of is:

```
resources :personality_reports, param: 'personality_report' do
  member do
    get 'diff/:id', to: 'personality_reports#action', as: 'diff_route'
  end
end
```

Where obviously to: is your controller#action, and as: is the name of your route. After running rake routes you will see this generates:

```
 diff_route_personality_report GET   /personality_reports/:personality_report_id/diff/:id(.:format)   personality_reports#action
```

Comment: Thanks - I've gone for this method so it doesn't require another controller.

Answer (score 1):

I think whatever you mentioned is good enough,

```
resources : personality_reports do
  resources :diffs, only: [:show]
end
```

So, routes like below,

```
personality_report_diff GET    /personality_reports/:personality_report_id/diffs/:id(.:format) diffs#show
```

NOTE: You can also make diff route in singular **resource :diff** if you want to make it as singular resource.

Comment: Thanks - I was thinking about that and discarded because I'd then have to have a DiffsController, but maybe that's the right path.